# Hibernate: What is the preferred way of updating an object?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We have a method decorated as @Transactional, we fetched object from database, then we change the state of object by calling some setter method for instance. This is an attached entity so when this method is executed all changes to the entity are committed back to database.

Why we should explicitly call update/save/merge/SaveOrUpdate? In my understanding we can live without invoking these method if it is an attached entity, I would like to know what I am missing here.

Let me rephrase my question. Am I loosing anything by not invoking these methods to update an attached entity? It looks like it is just a pragmatic practice to explicitly invoke any of these methods (update/save/merge/SaveOrUpdate).

Answer (score 0):

You loose documentation when doing this. 
Most developers do not know about this behaviour so they do not expect it. Usually you should have a save / create method in the service layer handling all save oeprations for this entity. This allows easier refactoring later on in a project when something needs to be done on save. 
Think about the situation of doing something like this when using the implicit save in your whole operation. You would have a nearly 100% chance of forgetting to add the additional code at at least one location.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the transactional write behind of Hibernate, all dirtied entities will be detected and flushed at the end of the enclosed transaction, just before it is committed. Hence, in your case of working on managed (or attached) entities, it should be fine. 
However, when the method is called from another layer with detached arguments (like calling service from web layer), the entities are not yet known by Hibernate hence, will not be flushed at the end of the transaction and you certainly are loosing some modifications here. Therefore, to be on the safe side, a call to save()/merge() is necessary at the end of the method to ensure that no modification is missed regardless how the method is used from other layers.

Comment: Yes my method has no argument, it fetches object from database, then updates it but I like your point that if a method has detached argument.